# NodeJS - What is the proper way to use multiple read-streams with single write-stream in Node?

Tags: node.js, node-streams

### Context:

There’s a third-party API that gets me an array of events based on the token I provide.
Say, if I have 5 tokens, I’ll have use each of the tokens, get all the events for that token (will require multiple API calls due to pagination), then process those events.
All the events of one token need to be processed sequentially. But, there is no sequence/ordering among tokens.
Also, an error in processing one token's event should abort further process for that token. But, it shouldn't affect processing of other tokens' events.
I'm using [objectMode](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_object_mode) for both the read and write streams.

### Question:

For processing of events, I’ve created a single Writable stream.
However I’m not sure what the best way to handle the read stream is.

- Should I create multiple read streams, one for each token, and pipe them all to a single write stream?

  ```js
  const tokens = ['token1', 'token2'];
  const myEventsWriter = new MyEventsWritable();  // single write stream
  tokens.forEach(token => new MyEventsReadable(token).pipe(myEventsWriter));  // multiple read streams
  ```

  My concern with this approach is, if there are a lot of tokens (each having a lot of events), the system will act weird and/or fail.
- Should I create a single read stream, that internally uses one token after the other to get events?
  i.e. Create a single read stream with an array of tokens. Once all the events of one token are pushed, discard that token and use the next one.
  This I feel might be simpler to implement. But I'm not sure if it's right to add that overhead of switching tokens in the read stream implementation.
- Should I create multiple read steams. Pipe one read stream into the write stream at a time. And when one read stream ends (or faces an error), unpipe and destroy that stream. And then pipe the next.
  This I feel might be a better approach. But, I'm a novice when it comes to Node streams and the approach feels fairly complex. I do not want to introduce any memory leaks due to the streams not being properly closed/handled.

Or is there a better way to handle this? The node version I'm using is v8.16.0.
Most of the examples I've found follow a simple `read-stream.pipe(transform-stream).pipe(write-stream)` example.
So, I'm pretty confused about how to handle cases involving multiple read/write streams. Any guidance is welcome.

Comment: Is there also a motivation for using streams? It is definitively doable, but complex stream patterns tend to be more difficult to maintain.

Comment: @jorgenkg Without streams, I'll need to fetch all events of a token before I can start processing them; one-by-one. If there are a lot events, that may cause memory issue. Streams let me fetch new data and process available data simultaneously. Also, they give me a control over how much data to hold at a time. That's why streams.
If the events didn't require to be processed one-by-one in the exact sequence they were received, I wouldn't have thought about using streams.
But, if you know a better way to do this, I'm open to hear it.

Comment: When piping multiple write streams to a single writable, the writable stream will be closed when the first readable stream closes. This issue may be avoided by propagating all the remote data via a single readable stream, ref (2) above. However, the script can still fetch data from all the tags concurrently, by pushing to a unified readable.